# Hierarchy visualization for genealogic tree

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I would like to represent a genealogic tree with d3.js in for of a Fanview such as in this aper:
http://www.cs.utah.edu/~draperg/research/fanchart/draperg_FHT08.pdf

One individual is the center, his parents are two arcs around it, then their parents, and so forth.

I managed to code this with “flat” data, but I do more complex things with this and it becomes very slow when I would like to manipulate data interactively, and animate. So I tried to use hierarchies. I managed to transform data into a tree and display it as a partition. When two parents are known, everything works fine. However when only one of the parents is known, it has to use only half of the arc size of the child. I could trick this to some extent with values. The problem is that a single mother has to be shifted at the end of the arc. Thus my question: can I shift some of the data depending on some criteria? Do I have to code a new hierarchy representation?

To help this out, there is a numbering system called SOSA. The root is 1, his father 2, mother 3, then grandparents are 4, 5, 6 and 7. The recursive relation is: SOSA(father(X)) = 2*SOSA(X), and SOSA(mother(X)) = 2*SOSA(X) + 1